# Compare given string answer to actual time?

Tags: java, string, time, compare, comparison

```
public static void time (String[] args) {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date = new Date();
    }
}

public class test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.println("What time is it?");
    int time = scan.nextInt();
    if(time = date) {                       // I know it's not correct but you get what I want
    System.out.println("That's right");
    else {
    ....
    }
    }
    }
}
```

So I basically want someone to answer the question by typing the actual time. Then I want to compare it with the exact current time and say wether it's true or not.

Comment: What is the date format in? Are you looking at comparing different date formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CheckTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Start your scanner
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What time is it?");
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        Date date = new Date();

        //Read the entire line as a String
        String time = scan.nextLine();

        //Format your datatetim in HH:mm format and compare the strings
        if (time.equals(df.format(date))) {                       // I know it's not correct but you get what I want
            System.out.println("That's right");
        } else {
            System.out.println("That's wrong");
        }
        //Never forget to close your scanner
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that really helped me!

Comment: @MyNames16James consider using H:mm in the formatter if you want to get rid of the leading zeros in time (if you want to use more human-friendly 8:06 instead of 08:06)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `java.time.LocalTime` class.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String suppliedTimeString = args[0];

    LocalTime suppliedTime = LocalTime.parse(suppliedTimeString);

    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.MINUTES);

    if (suppliedTime.compareTo(currentTime) == 0) {
      System.out.println("That's right");
    } else {
      System.out.println("That's wrong");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For comparing date you can use this method:

```
    private static boolean compareDateWithVariance(LocalDateTime date1, LocalDateTime date2, Long varianceInSeconds){
  return date1.isAfter(date2.minusSeconds(varianceInSeconds)) && date1.isBefore(date2.plusSeconds(varianceInSeconds)) ;
}
```

and this can be used for parsing your input to LocalDateTime:

```
String str = "1986-04-08 12:30";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the user to enter the date time in a particular format and then use the good old equals for camparison.
For e.g, i am using the **YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm** here, SimpleDateFormat helps me parse the date.

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");
Date dateEntered = sdf.parse(new Scanner(System.in).nextLine());
if(dateEntered.equals(dateReference)) {
 ...
}
System.out.println("time " + dateEntered.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much!